# Systemd socket unit from generator starts out dead

Tags: systemd

I've written a systemd unit generator that generates simple socket and service units that accept connections and hands them to `systemd-socket-proxyd`. On an Ubuntu 16.04 system (systemd 229), `systemctl daemon-reload` runs the generator and the generated units appear in `/run/systemd/generator/`:

```
# cat /run/systemd/generator/sdtcpproxy-127.0.0.1-5555.socket
[Unit]
Description=TCP proxy to 127.0.0.1:5555
Requires=network-online.target
After=network.target network-online.target multi-user.target

[Socket]
ListenStream=127.0.0.1:5500
ListenStream=127.0.0.1:5551

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

(I wasn't originally using the `Requires` and `After` lines; I put those in an attempt to ensure it was starting at the right time. I don't actually think that they're necessary.)

but they start out disabled:

```
 sdtcpproxy-127.0.0.1-5555.socket - TCP proxy to 127.0.0.1:5555
   Loaded: loaded (/run/systemd/generator/sdtcpproxy-127.0.0.1-5555.socket; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
   Listen: 127.0.0.1:5500 (Stream)
           127.0.0.1:5551 (Stream)
```

`sockets.target` is active according to `systemctl status`. I'm not clear if the `bad` in the message above is actually a real problem or if it's [bug #2348](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2348).

`systemctl enable` on the unit produces the error message `Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory`. `systemctl start` on the unit starts it up and it runs just fine.

What am I doing wrong or forgetting here?

Comment: For what it's worth, putting `enable sdtcpproxy-*.socket` in `/etc/systemd/system-preset/50-sdtcpproxy.preset` does set it to 'vendor preset: enabled'. Looking at other generated units, though, it appears that they ought not be enabled, however, just started. So I guess my question, more clearly is, 'How do I get systemd to start these automatically'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `bad` in the message is not a problem; that's just a bug in that particular version of `systemd`.

The problem is that the `.socket` unit is not enabled. Generated units cannot be enabled in the normal way (`systemctl enable` does not look in `/run/systemd/generator/` or similar paths for unit files); it must be enabled by the generator itself by creating an appropriate `.wants` subdirectory with symlinks to the units in it, just as `systemctl enable` would do for non-generated units. So in this case, have the generator create both the unit and the symlink to it:

```
/run/systemd/generator/sdtcpproxy-127.0.0.1-5555.socket
/run/systemd/generator/socket.target.wants/sdtcpproxy-127.0.0.1-5555.socket
    -> /run/systemd/generator/sdtcpproxy-127.0.0.1-5555.socket
```

and when your system boots or you do a `systemctl daemon-reload` systemd will start the socket unit which will then be listening, and will start the `.service` unit when it receives the first connection.